# Of the difference between zeugma and syllepsis

Tags: figures-of-speech, syllepsis, zeugma

I am confused about what is the relative meaning of *zeugma* compared to *syllepsis*, both in its current meaning and possibly in former understandings of these words.

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has:

> **zeugma**
>   a figure of speech in which a word applies to two others in different senses (e.g., *John and his license expired last week*) or to two others of which it semantically suits only one (e.g., *with weeping eyes and hearts*).
>
> ---
>
> **syllepsis**
>   a figure of speech in which a word is applied to two others in different senses (e.g., *caught the train and a bad cold*) or to two others of which it grammatically suits only one (e.g., *neither they nor it is working*).

According to this, there is some overlap, though *zeugma* is more about semantics and *syllepsis* about grammar. Online sources on this issue conflict, with [some](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/syllepsis.htm) insisting one the difference (“not to be confused with zeugma”) and [others](http://literaryzone.com/?p=146) stating that the two have merged.

Can someone offer a clear view of the differences, present or past, between these terms?

Comment: I thought that Zeugma was a specific case of syllepsis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED, in the definition of *syllepsis* reports that's another term for *zeugma*.

The *Collin English Dictionary* reports *syllepsis* means:

> (in grammar or rhetoric) the use of a single sentence construction in which a verb, adjective, etc is made to cover two syntactical functions, as the verb form *have* in "she and they have promised to come."

Also the *Collin English Dictionary* reports that *syllepsis* is another word for *zeugma* (as second meaning).

Answer (score 16):

I have always understood the difference between *zeugma* and *syllepsis* to be that *syllepsis* is used to create a semantic dissonance with intentionally humorous effect. For example, here is Ambrose Bierce's definition of the word piano from his *The Devil's Dictionary*

> **piano** n. A parlor utensil for subduing the impenitent visitor. It is operated by depressing the keys of the machine and the spirits of the audience.

*Zeugma*, on the other hand is supposed to be used for dramatic or felicitous effect. Or so I was told when I studied rhetoric.

The sad fact is, the meanings of these two terms have become inextricably yoked together (ha ha) over the years, blurring the distinctions and our ability to articulate them (again, ha ha).

Comment: I got the 'yoke' reference but not 'articulate'.

Comment: @Mitch: To articulate something means to express it clearly.

Comment: @Mitch It was a zeugma.

Comment: @Mitch: one meaning of "articulate" is "make clear, distinct, and precise in relation to other parts."

Comment: @Lambie: Maybe I'm old, but in college there were courses offered in it, so I took one.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the definitions in my first "real" dictionary (New World Dictionary of the American Language, Second College Edition, 1980), I've always understood *zeugma* to be the clever one and *syllepsis* to be the boring one.

> **zeugma**:  a figure of speech in which a single word, usually a verb or
>   adjective, is syntactically related to two or more words, with only
>   one of which it seems logically connected (Ex: The room was not light,
>   but his fingers were)

vs

> **syllepsis**:  a grammatical construction in which a single word is used to modify or govern syntactically two or more words in the same
>   sentence, though it can grammatically agree with only one of them
>   (Ex.: either they or I am wrong)

Actually, I find I have a cavil with the above definition of zeugma:  although it contrasts "logically connected" with an implied "illogically connected," the example illustrates "concrete" vs. "figurative."

Anyway, the point is that, according to these two definitions, *syllepsis* represents a grammatical strain; *zeugma* is more of a semantical mixture.

Now, from another "real" dictionary (The Compact Edition of the Oxford English Dictionary, Complete Text Reproduced Micrographically, 1971):

> **zeugma**:  A figure by which a single word is made to refer to two or more words in the sentence; esp. when properly applying in sense to
>   only one of them, or applying to them in different senses; but
>   formerly more widely, including, e.g., the use of the same predicate,
>   without repetition, with two or more subjects; also sometimes applied
>   to cases of irregular *construction*, in which the single word agrees
>   *grammatically* with only one of the other words to which it refers (more properly called Syllepsis).

vs

> **syllepsis**:  A figure by which a word, or a particular form or inflexion of a word, is made to refer to two or more other words in
>   the same sentence, while properly applying to or agreeing with only
>   one of them (e.g. a masc. adj. qualifying two sbs., masc. and fem.; a
>   sing. verb serving as predicate to two subjects, sing. and pl.), or
>   applying to them in different senses (e.g., literal and metaphorical).

Here, the overlap between the two words is brought out a bit more; however, the distinction can still be seen:  *zeugma* causes a word to serve double (or more) duty in terms of sense; *syllepsis* does so in terms of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A syllepsis is a zeugma that's *wrong*.

For example, "Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears" is a zeugma.  Each of the first three words is a vocative for the rest of the sentence.

"You held your breath and the door for me" is a zeugma that is a syllepsis, because "held" is used to mean two, incompatible, things.  It's hard to imagine a syllepsis that wouldn't sound jarring and incongruous.

Comment: That's not how "zeugma" is usually used by linguists, where it usually in fact covers your second example.

Comment: Did you mean "[vocative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case)" instead of "locative"? (Even though neither case exists in English?)

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe --  did mean vocative (now corrected, thanks), but while English lacks a distinct vocative case for nouns, we certainly have vocative phrases, buddy.  And StackExchange actually has a specific vocative marker, the @ sign!

Answer (score 0):

A practical if arbitrary distinction: syllepsis should denote a grammatical incident, for example a disagreement as "None of these texts are known in their original form." [the verb agreeing with "these texts"] instead of "None of these texts is known in its original form." [the verb agreeing with "none"]

The ambiguity could be prevented by the restricted use of "zeugma" as a figure of speech only.

Answer (score 0):

About 200,000 words are said to comprise the English language. Many of these have very similar meanings, or convey subtle differences. This makes English a rich resource for precise expression, but it can also create problems, such as the subject of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Jane Austen wrote:

> Mr and Mrs Moreland were all compliance, and Catherine all happiness.

A lot of commentary on syllepsis implies that Austen’s sentence is ungrammatical. I disagree with this commentary.

Comment: You should clarify how this answers the question of the difference between zeugma and syllepsis.

Comment: In order to answer the question of the difference between zeugma and syllepsis, it is reasonable to take account of what authoritative commentators have said about this subject. What was at the back of my mind in my previous comment is (i) that expert commentary here seems unconvincing and (ii) that therefore it is difficult, perhaps impossible, to specify the difference between zeugma and syllepsis.

Comment: In my original comment, I was also implying my reservations about what Wikipedia says about this subject. The Wikipedia account - which had been cited by another commentator - implicitly gives credence to the notion that the Austen sentence I cited is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford Companion to the English Language offers the following account of Zeugma

> 16c: through Latin from Greek *zeûgma* yoking. (1) also *syllepsis*. In rhetoric, a phrase in which a word, usually a verb, is followed by two or more other words commonly collocate with it, but not together. 'The morning brought misty sunshine and the nurse.' (Mary Stewart, *Wildfire at midnight* 1956). A figurative use usually precedes a literal use; in Pope's *Rape of the Lock* (1714), the heroine might 'stain her honour, or her new brocade' and 'lose her heart, or necklace, at a ball'. (2) A form of ellipsis regarded as poor style: *I was on the phone and my bags on the ground* is ungrammatical in standard English.  Zeugma is common in such constructions as *X is as big if not bigger than Y*, from which *X is as big than Y.* can be extracted. The balanced form is *X is as big as if not bigger than Y*.

I have to admit that my edition of OCEL dates back to 1992, a venerable three decades. It does not provide a separate account of syllepsis. Nor does the Cambridge English Dictionary.

Collins dictionary does provide an entry for *syllepsis*, which offers a distinctive usage in addition to sharing that of its more established cousin.

> 1. (in grammar or rhetoric) the use of a single sentence construction in which a verb, adjective, etc is made to cover two syntactical functions, as the verb form *have* in she and they *have* promised to come.
> 2. another word for zeugma.

If that is a fair account of usage, then the distinctive first definition in Collins is more about grammar than wit or style.  Merriam Webster defines syllepsis drawing the same distinctions but the other way around - zeugma first.

If there is a difference between these two terms it is that syllepsis, covers a specifically grammatical non-standard usage, which crops up not infrequently in writing.  The other usage, as in:-

> He refreshed himself with the morning air and the contents of his brandy flask.

Wikipedia offers a useful discussion of the two words at

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis

It is well worth a read.

Answer (score -1):

Breaking the "covered" or "connected" words apart and connecting them with the "unifying" word makes clear the difference.
Ex: "Friends, Romans, countrymen lend me your ears." This breaks apart to "Friends, lend me your ears; Romans, lend me your ears;  countrymen, lend me your ears." "Lend" fits with each of the linked words correctly and with the same meaning of "lend."
Ex: "Piano: played by depressing the keys and the spirits of the listeners." This breaks apart to "Piano,  played by depressing the keys; also, depressing the spirits of the listeners." "Depressing" has a sense in each of these phrases, one being physical, the other being psychological. It is this unexpected change of "matrix" that induces humor or dis-settlement in the reader.
I leave it to the reader to decide which is which. [Hint: they are in alphabetical order.]

Comment: You should clarify how this answers the question of the difference between zeugma and syllepsis.

Comment: You should also add supporting references. The words are obviously ill-defined; people selecting different specifying definitions will never agree.

Comment: I thught the hint would make it clear. My favorite zeugma is a line from the Limelighters song "Have Some Madera, My Dear.." It went: 
"When he said, 'What in heavens, she made no reply, up her mind, and a dash for the door."  Beautiful, no?