# What's the term for when two related words are used in a different sense, often one literally and one metaphorically?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Apologies for the title, I found it difficult to describe.

If I say *he took his hat and his leave* I believe that is called syllepsis or zeugma. Another example would be *he bolted his food, the door, and down the street*.

But is there a term for an expression like *where the gin is cold but the piano's hot*?

*Cold* is used literally, *hot* metaphorically. It seems related to the first examples or does it have a more specific name - or no name at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Of the difference between zeugma and syllepsis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23592/of-the-difference-between-zeugma-and-syllepsis)

Answer (score 1):

I think, in the general sense, you're describing a pun—specifically, a homonymic (or polysemic) pun. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun#Homographic):

> Homonymic puns, another common type, arise from the exploitation of words which are both homographs and homophones. The statement “Being in politics is just like playing golf: you are trapped in one bad lie after another” puns on the two meanings of the word lie as “a deliberate untruth” and as “the position in which something rests”…A homonymic pun may also be polysemic, in which the words must be homonymic and also possess related meanings, a condition that is often subjective.

Comment: Thanks, but "hot" and "cold" aren't homonyms so that's not really what I was looking for.

Comment: The example given is certainly a play on words (making use of peculiarities possessed by words, here different available senses, the non-relevant one of one word linking to the sense in which the other is used. As you say, polysemic punning.  It's clever and entertaining if not hilarious, so I'd _agree_ it's an example of punning.